# What is the difference between 「食べるいいですか」 and 「食べていいですか」

Tags: grammar

They both mean "Can you/I eat?"
So can they be used interchangeably?

I know that the て-form is used when speaking a command to someone so is it a more direct(?) form of asking a question? Like asking a question to someone who is superior to you?

Comment: As sawa wrote, 食べるいいですか is ungrammatical.  Moreover, 食べていいですか does not mean “Can you eat?”

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the former is ungrammatical, the latter is grammatical. They cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: About the meaning of the -te form... In this example, it's not a form of command. -te form can have many meanings, and in this case, it's used to connect the verb to the i-adj, which acts as a verb. Literally, it's something like "I eat and it's okay?".

Comment: @alexandrec Your explanation is almost good, but i-adj is an i-adj, it is not a verb. The verb (copula) is `です`.